# Display multiple youtube videos in a page using youtub iframe api Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube-iframe-api

Hello I am using Angular 6 and I  have my videos component where I am initializing the youtube iframe API and display the youtube video with the particular video ID (embedded id)

here is my videos.component.ts

```
  public YT: any;
  public player: any;
  public reframed: Boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
    window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = (e) => {
      this.YT = window['YT'];
      this.reframed = false;
      this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
        videoId: 'z4JUm0Bq9AM',
      });
    };
  }

  init() {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }
}
```

Here is my videos.component.html

```
<div class="width">
    <div id="player">
    </div>
</div>
```

everything is working fine!!

Here I want to show multiple videos in that single page where I will be getting the video ID from the database.
So, I have tried this...
from another component, I will be getting the video ID's as an array of strings I am sending these id's as an input parameter for the videos.component

```
    <div *ngFor="let video of topic._source.videos">
        <app-videos [video]='video'></app-videos>
    </div>
```

here video is the embeded id of the youtube video.

now my videos.component.ts is

```
export class VideosComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() video: string;

  public YT: any;
  public player: any;
  public reframed: Boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
    console.log(this.video)
    window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = (e) => {
      this.YT = window['YT'];
      this.reframed = false;
      this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {
        videoId: this.video,
      });
    };
  }

  init() {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }
}
```

In the console log, I can see the three video ids are coming here. but I can see only the first ID's video.

So I am actually trying to display all the videos. I mean for all the id's which I get from the database. Sorry, if I am doing something fundamentally wrong. please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I've understood right, `_source.videos` is an array of property, and you can just see one video instead of three istance of your `app-video`, right?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi yes it is an array of strings.

Comment: I don't get it, you are passing video as an input but the video component as no `@Input()`. Did you just delete it before posting or what? Also debugging like this is kinda hard, can you provide a plunker?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi there is an input() statement before the public YT: any;

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i will try to provide a plunker